# comparison with NULL date gives NULL value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

This code results in NULL. `sale_jan_dt` and `sale_feb_dt` both `datetime` columns.

```
s.sale_feb_dt = 2022-09-01 01:19:00.000
s.sale_jan_dt = NULL

select
    case 
        when s.sale_jan_dt >= s.sale_feb_dt
            then cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_feb_dt, 20) as datetime)             
        else
            cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_jan_dt, 20) as datetime) 
    end as min_sales_month
from sales s
```

Would this code return a datetime value or string? I have to use the min_sales_month in date calculations.

```
select
    case 
        when isnull(s.sale_jan_dt, '2100-12-31 23:59:59') >= s.sale_feb_dt
            then cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_feb_dt, 20) as datetime) 
            else cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_jan_dt, 20) as datetime) 
    end as min_sales_month
from 
    sales s
```

Comment: Why not test your second attempt and find out? You don't need to ask here a bout whether or not the attempt will work; you are in a much better position to test the attempt as we don't have access to your table.

Comment: I did test my 2nd attempt and it worked but fails while doing a full load and I am unable to find where the issue is.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Are you getting an error? What is the error? Are you getting unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? Something else?

Comment: You are handling the case where s.sale_jan_dt is null, but not s.sale_feb_dt

Comment: CASE WHEN s.sale_jan_dt IS NULL AND s.sale_feb_dt IS NULL THEN ... WHEN  s.sale_jan_dt IS NULL THEN ... WHEN s.sale_feb_dt IS NULL THEN ... WHEN s.sale_jan_dt >= s.sale_feb_dt THEN ... ELSE ... END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change comparison, swap result, and I believe you'll get what you want.

```sql
select
    case 
        when s.sale_jan_dt >= s.sale_feb_dt or s.sale_jan_dt is null
            then cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_feb_dt, 20) as datetime)             
        else
            cast(convert(char(20), s.sale_jan_dt, 20) as datetime) 
    end as min_sales_month
from sales s
```

Comment: Any of the dates can be NULL. SO swapping wont be an option.

Comment: @NikkiMalhotra what should be return if both `NULL`?

Comment: If both are NULL, value should be NULL. min_sales_month should return the minimum of 2 dates.